# Zend_Table_Db and Zend_Paginator and Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have the following query:

```
$this->select()
 ->where("`name` LIKE ?",'%'.mysql_escape_string($name).'%')
```

Now I have the Zend_Paginator code:

```
        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(
                // $d is an instance of Zend_Db_Select
                new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($d)
        );      

        $paginator->getAdapter()->setRowCount(200);

        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(15)
                ->setPageRange(10)
                ->setCurrentPageNumber($pag);

        $this->view->data = $paginator;
```

As you see I'm passing the data to the view using `$this->view->data = $paginator`
Before I didn't had `$paginator->getAdapter()->setRowCount(200);`I could determinate If I have any data or not, what I mean with data, if the query has some results, so If the query has some results I show the to the user, if not, I need to show them a message(No results!)

But in this moment I don't know how can I determinate this, since `count($paginator)` doesn't work anymore because of `$paginator->getAdapter()->setRowCount(200);`and I'm using this because it taks about 7 sec for Zend_Paginator to count the page numbers.

So how can I find If my query has any results?

Comment: "doesn't work anymore" - what does it returns as a result?

Comment: Doesn't work anymore it means; that I can't count $paginator anymore, because it will allways be the same value since i'm using $paginator->getAdapter()->setRowCount(200);

Comment: A bit of a blind guess as I never had the need to use setRowCount: does ``$paginator->count()`` help? It returns the number of the pages.

Comment: No, since I'm using setRowCount to set the total number pages!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you setRowCount() to a magic number?  If whatever method Z_P is using to discover the total number of rows is taking a long time, you might want to override it that way, but you'd want to compute the actual value, wouldn't you?

In most cases, Z_P ought to automatically get the right number (internally, via a subquery).  If that subquery is taking too long, you can try building your own Zend_Db_Select to perform the count, and pass that to setRowCount().

Comment: Yeah thats the main problem actually, setRowCount(), but as you can see here http://tinypic.com/r/vesy9c/6 the count query takes a lot of time, the table is also really big, million of rows, can you help me to write a better count query..or what should I do?

Comment: If I see it correctly, that's 0.00007 seconds, not 7 seconds (7*10^(-5)). on that picture all the 3 queries together take 2.7 seconds.

Comment: Those are 7 seconds, I have just tested it again :)

Comment: You're going to have to optimize your database.  I don't know enough about fulltext indexing in mySQL, but you might want to investigate.  The root problem here is that you're using LIKE with a leading % on the right-hand side, which means your poor DB has to scan every record looking for matches.

Comment: Also, you don't need to `mysql_escape_string` the sql param, as ZF uses prepared statements  and placeholders (the `?` in your query). And the backticks in your sql will be a pain if you change your RDBMS (ie. from mysql to postgresql). Consider `Zend_Db_Select::quoteIdentifier()`.

Comment: Btw. what are you using to get those query times?